# C# windows application stop working when start big for loop process

Tags: c#, windows

my program stop working  when it get into for loop I solved it whit  Application.DoEvents(); but it realy slow down the program  how can i solve it??

```
for (int b = 10011000; b < 99999999; b++)
        {
            //code

            if (//condition )
            {



                try
                {
        ///////

                }


                catch
                {
          //////
                }
            }
            else
            {
        //////
            }
            Application.DoEvents();

        }
```

Comment: In windows forms you can use `BackgroundWorker` to make background task without blocking UI.

Comment: dont forget accept my answer ;-)

Comment: The `has stopped working` is because the message queue of the main window isn't processed. This is because the gui thread is executing your for loop. Like @AlessandroD'Andria said, use a [BackgroundWorker msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples).  or [BackgroundWorker Tutorial](https://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, using `Application.DoEvents()` is never really the best way to do things.

I would suggest putting your loop inside its own function and then calling it on its own thread. This way the UI thread will keep running separately while your loop does it's thing. There are other ways to achieve this such as using `Tasks` and `CallBacks` or `async` methods if you want to do a little research and decide which is the most appropriate for your situation.

Something like this:

```
Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(()=>myLoopMethod));
backgroundThread.Start();
```

Or:

```
Task myLoop = new Task(() => myLoopMethod));
myLoop.Start();
```

Although I don't have access to an IDE at the moment to check that syntax.

Comment: tnx alot I will do that
actually I don't need UI after it start too process I just want the program do it's work

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty intensive for loop you have going on there. Why don't you make use of an [async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx) model instead?

MSDN also tenders a [caution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx) when making use of this DoEvents.

And your case seems like it would be a good candidate to hand off to be executed asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

you need to run it on other thread or task

like this:

```
Task task = new Task( () => { /* your code */ } );
task.Start();
```

by this code your application never stop but don't forget for changing in UI  parameters you need invoking

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => { /*your code*/ }));
```

for more info watch this links :

https://www.dotnetperls.com/async

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189374/The-Basics-of-Task-Parallelism-via-C

**update**

and for speedup your code is good to use parallel.for .
whach this link

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/608/csharp-parallel-for-loop-method`

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ParallelFor
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Using C# For Loop \n");

        for(int i=0; i <=10; i++){
            Console.WriteLine("i = {0}, thread = {1}",
                i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nUsing Parallel.For \n");

        Parallel.For(0, 10, i =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("i = {0}, thread = {1}", i,
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}`
```

Comment: tnx It's get job done but It's realy slow how can i speed it up

Comment: use parallel.for for this it wil speed up your code

Comment: watch the update of answer and dont forget accept it ;-)